# Need powershell script(or any) to get page visit count on all site pages in a site collection(for a year)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, 2019, analytics, audit-log-reports

I'm using SharePoint 2019 and looking to get user visits count on all site pages using powershell or .Net or by any means.

> I have tried usage report which is not providing the individual pages visits. 
>   I have tried audit report also, but for some reason visit count is very less which is wrong. 
>   I'm able get month wise visit count for all the sites and sub sites but i want site pages visit count separately.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you can use search API. try this if it works for you YourSiteURL/_api/search/query?querytext='path:YourSiteURL'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers'

Comment: Do you have page request included in your usage logging? REF: https://blog.syskit.com/analytics-in-sharepoint-on-premises

Comment: Yes Marek, it is enabled, can i extract data from analytics?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the two articles below:

1.Step by steps on how to display Most Visited Sites with number of view count in SharePoint 2013 Web Analytics.

https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-most-visited-sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/

2.SharePoint 2013: Showing Page Views within a SharePoint Page.

http://blog.meenavalli.in/post/page-views-hit-counter-on-a-sharepoint-page

Answer (score 0):

As you are on prem you could use the IIS logs to determine specific usage. Have a look at the log parser studio, there are some nice examples prepared by Exchange team that can be an starting point for you. It allows you to export the queries as PowerShell.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Log-Parser-Studio-2-0-is-now-available/ba-p/593266

Comment: IIS logs are stored only for last 30 days in our server, I want a report for a year

Comment: Try the popularity trends https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/view-usage-reports

Comment: Already tried popularity trends which doesn't help my case as i need an individual site page visits for a year(month wise)

Comment: To view the Popularity Trends report for a library or list item

Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Visitors group.

In the site collection, browse to the library or list that contains the item for which you want to view the Popularity Trends report.

Select the item that you want to view the Popularity Trends report for, and then do one of the following:

For a library, click the FILES tab, and then, on the ribbon, click Popularity Trends.

For a list, click the ITEMS tab, and then, on the ribbon, click Popularity Trends.